# invalid access token when using FBSDKGameRequestDialog

Tags: ios, facebook

I've been integrating the latest(ver 4.2) Facebook SDK with my iOS app.
I've successfully proceeded the login flow.
But when it comes to game request.
I always get a callback of FBSDKGameRequestDialog:didFailWithError
while the error message is "invalid access_token"

I check the [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] right before the request.
And it's not null and is not expired.

Now, I'm totally freaking out. Does any one have any ideas? Thanks

Here's the code:

```
- (void) startFBInviteWithTitle:(NSString *)title withMsg:(NSString *)msg withIDs:(NSArray *)ids {

FBSDKAccessToken* token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];

if(!token){
    NSLog(@"NO AccessToken");
    return;
}
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
// Look at FBSDKGameRequestContent for futher optional properties
gameRequestContent.message = msg;
gameRequestContent.title = title;
gameRequestContent.recipientSuggestions = ids;

[FBSDKGameRequestDialog showWithContent:gameRequestContent delegate:self];
```

}

Comment: Do you also have the error code? This might be related to the access token used, but that is private so you should not share it here. Perhaps you can file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

Comment: Did you try to logout and login again? ([[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init] logOut];) ..
Also I would remove the recipientSuggestions field to try first running it without any additional fields..